# AWS cloudformation: How to run cfn-nag locally in Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, lint

I have a cloud formation template where I have all the resources and details for the project.

I have the cfn-lint setup locally and it is running perfectly fine. However when I push the code changes, build fails at deployment stage due to cfn-nag stating some simple changes which could be fixed.

I'm using windows machine and I need a way to run this cfn-nag locally so that I could check this just like cfn-lint and fix them locally instead of waiting 40 minutes for build till it reaches deployment stage.

I referred several posts online, found below two helpful

https://stelligent.com/2018/03/23/validating-aws-cloudformation-templates-with-cfn_nag-and-mu/
https://github.com/stelligent/cfn_nag

What is the difference between cfn-nag and cfn-lint and why lint is not failing on what cfn-nag is complaining about?

The above links have some instructions on Ruby and Brew but I'm using Nodejs, felt lost. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CFN-Nag** looks for patterns in AWS CloudFormation templates that may indicate insecure infrastructure,

Ex:

IAM rules that are too permissive (wildcards),
Security group rules that are too permissive (wildcards),
Access logs that aren’t enabled,
Encryption that isn’t enabled,

**CFN-Lint** scans the AWS CloudFormation template by processing a collection of Rules, where every rule handles a specific function check or validation of the template. It validates against AWS CloudFormation Resource specification.

This collection of rules can be extended with custom rules using the --append-rules argument.

Ex: Whitespaces, alignment(YAML), type checks, valid values for resource properties, and other best practices.

Those two links you previded above have all the information needed, just not directly for a Nodejs developer using a Windows machine.

**Step1**: Pull the docket image `stelligent/cfn-nag`

**Step2**: Add the script to your package.json for cfn-nag

Ex:

```
"scripts" : {
       "cfn:nag": "cfn-nag"
  }
```

If you're using docker-compose.yml

Add the cfn-nag image details to your `docker-compose.yml` like below

```
cfn-nag:
   image: "stelligent/cfn-nag"
   volumes:
      -./path_of_cfn_file_to_copy: /path_to_copy_to
   command: ${COMMAND: -/path_to_copy_tp/cfn_file}
```

Just set the scripts in package.json to run via docker-compose

```
"cfn:nag": "docker-compose run --rm cfn-nag"
```